# Why the scroll animation is not disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Why the disable function is not working?

Without the `stop()` function, it is working well but the animation is lagging from the 400 of the animation's and with `stop()` the scroll is not disabled.

If I scroll the wheel fast, the animation stops and when I stop the wheel, the animation is beginning.

Here is my page's link http://web.100mb.ro/tutti/

```
$("#section-five").bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta <= 0) {

    }
    else {
        disable_scroll();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#section-four").offset().top
        }, 400,'swing',function(){
            enable_scroll();
        });
    }
});


var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.eevnt;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Comment: Add a flag as a global variable `var mouseDisabled = false;`, make it  `mouseDisabled = true;` inside your `disable_scroll` function and `mouseDisabled = false;` inside your `enable_scroll` function. Then check the flag on every `mousewheel` before you do anything else, if it is true `return`.

Comment: It  is changing from false to true but nothing is the same (i changed in the page, in the console log u can see)

Answer (score 0):

Your `disable_scroll` function seems to be adding a scroll event listener, while your `enable_scroll` function removes it.